# Update having count() = 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a query where I update `table1` where column `Index1` = 3122411, with no duplicates in the column `Index1` where column `user` = 290045

Pseudo code:

If `user` = 290045 and `Index1` = 3122411 where count(Index1) = 1 
set `Index` = 500

[Sample data]:

```
user   | line_number|header|Index1
290045 |0           |0     |3122411
290045 |1           |0     |3122411
8733   |0           |0     |66
```

My code doesn't update the table at all:

```
update table1
set Index1 = 500
where user = 290045 and Index1 in
(
    select Index1
    from table1
    where Index1 = 3122411 and Index1 in(
    select * from
    (
    select Index1
    from table1
    group by Index1
    having count(*) = 1
    ) x
)
)
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MySQL server version**

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   `user` INTEGER,
>   `line_number` INTEGER,
>   `header` INTEGER,
>   `Indexi` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO table1
>   (`user`, `line_number`, `header`, `Indexi`)
> VALUES
>   ('290045', '0', '0', '3122411'),
>   ('290045', '1', '0', '3122411'),
>   ('290045', '2', '0', '833'),
>   ('8733', '0', '0', '66');
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE table1 t1 INNER JOIN (SELECT `Indexi`,`user`, COUNT(*) cnt1 FROM table1 GROUP BY `Indexi`,`user`) t2
> USING (`Indexi`,`user`)
> SET indexi = 500
> WHERE user = 290045 AND Indexi = 3122411 and cnt1 = 1
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM table1
> ```
>
> ```
>   user | line_number | header |  Indexi
> -----: | ----------: | -----: | ------:
> 290045 |           0 |      0 | 3122411
> 290045 |           1 |      0 | 3122411
> 290045 |           2 |      0 |     833
>   8733 |           0 |      0 |      66
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e09638887cb44df9e943fad7604b7a9a)*

That changes nothing

**SQL SERVER version**

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   [user] INT,
>   line_number INT,
>   header INT,
>   Indexi INT
> );
>
> INSERT INTO table1
>   ([user], line_number, header, Indexi)
> VALUES
>   ('290045', '0', '0', '3122411'),
>   ('290045', '1', '0', '3122411'),
>   ('290045', '2', '0', '833'),
>   ('8733', '0', '0', '66');
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 4 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE table1
>
> SET indexi = 500
> FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN (SELECT Indexi,[user], COUNT(*) cnt1 FROM table1 GROUP BY Indexi,[user]) t2
> ON t1.Indexi = t2.Indexi AND t1.[user] = t2.[user]
> WHERE t1.[user] = 290045 AND t1.Indexi = 3122411 and cnt1 = 1
> GO
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM table1
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
>   user | line_number | header |  Indexi
> -----: | ----------: | -----: | ------:
> 290045 |           0 |      0 | 3122411
> 290045 |           1 |      0 | 3122411
> 290045 |           2 |      0 |     833
>   8733 |           0 |      0 |      66
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e0e075c09f023a98eb45a5e401998400)*

For you next request

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   [user] INT,
>   line_number INT,
>   header INT,
>   Indexi INT
> );
>
> INSERT INTO table1
>   ([user], line_number, header, Indexi)
> VALUES
>   ('290045', '0', '0', '3122411'),
>   ('290045', '1', '0', '85'),
>   ('290045', '2', '0', '833'),
>   ('8733', '0', '0', '66')
>   ;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 4 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE table1
>
> SET indexi = 500
> FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN (SELECT Indexi,[user], COUNT(*) cnt1 FROM table1 GROUP BY Indexi,[user]) t2
> ON t1.Indexi = t2.Indexi AND t1.[user] = t2.[user]
> WHERE (t1.[user] = 290045 AND t1.Indexi = 3122411 and cnt1 = 1) 
> AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.[user] = 290045 AND t1.Indexi = 3122411)
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 1 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM table1
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
>   user | line_number | header | Indexi
> -----: | ----------: | -----: | -----:
> 290045 |           0 |      0 |    500
> 290045 |           1 |      0 |     85
> 290045 |           2 |      0 |    833
>   8733 |           0 |      0 |     66
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8ba65a34cdc78aaa4bb80755512e0623)*

Comment: Edited my original post.

Comment: then please add data and table show the problem more clearly

Comment: Your query as you can see changes nothing because userid 290045  and index1 3122411 is there twice

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a mistake the version im targeting is sql-server not mysql. Sorry for the confusion @nbk

Comment: I added the code for sql server, but thos stoll changes nothing no update because the count for userid 290045 and index1 3122411  is still 2

Comment: Would it be possible to set `Indexi` = 500 if  `Indexi` = 3122411, `user` = 290045 AND a different row with `user` = 290045 and `Indexi` = 85 ?

Comment: yes replace t1.Indexi = 3122411 wuth (t1.Indexi = 3122411 or t1.Indexi = 85) and it would change both rows if they are unique

Comment: This changes both the `Indexi` to 500 if the table only contains 1x `Indexi = 3122411` and `Indexi = 85`. I want the query to only set the value to 500 if  row1 has `Indexi = 3122411`, `user = 290045` AND row2 has `Indexi = 85` and `user = 290045`. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: that should at least give a upvote, i changed the data so that you can see that it changes something

Comment: Works like a charm, I appreciate the help a lot! I'd upvote you, but I have yet to receive 15 reputation

Answer (score -1):

This answers the original version of the question.

If I understand correctly, you can do this with `update`/`join`:

```
update table1 t1 cross join
       (select user, index, count(*) as cnt
        from table1
        where user = 290045 and Index = 3122411 
        group by user, Index
       ) tt1
       using (user, index)
    set index = 500
    where cnt = 1 ;
```

Note that `index` is a really bad name for a column because it is a SQL keyword.

Comment: I'm getting an error where the update line is expecting a set func instead of t1.

Comment: @187Ante . . . I don't understand your comment at all.  This should be valid MySQL syntax.

Comment: `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 't1'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near 'tt1'.`
At t1 it's expecting a set

Comment: I made a mistake @Gordon Linoff, the version I'm targeting is sql-server not MySql sorry for the confusion.